# Element not visible in protractor ionic

Tags: protractor

I have been testing a user acceptance testing using protractor and I have got something uncaught terrible bug ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
....

Here is the element that I need to refer using protractor.

```
<button style="" class="button back-button buttons  button-clear  header-item" ng-click="$ionicGoBack()">
  <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i> 
  <span style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" class="back-text"><span class="default-title hide">Back</span>
 <span class="previous-title">Power of Attorney/Authentication</span></span></button
```

>

I use this protractor syntax to locate this element

```
var btn = element(by.css('button.button.back-button.buttons.button- clear.header-item'));

btn.click(then(function(){


  // I do something with it here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The css selector which you have written does not seem correct.

```
var btn = element(by.css('.back-button'));

btn.click(then(function(){
// Do something
});
```

Since as per your snippet `.back-button` looks unique so above code should work.

Other css locators you can also try with:

`.button.back-button`

`.button.back-button.buttons.button-clear.header-item`

Comment: Even if above does not work try adding some wait condition there. Probably `browser.sleep(500);`

Comment: Thank you for all seeing my post but according to your suggestions neither  of the method doesn't work the same error 'Element not visible:..." will occur. Could you please see it deeply?